# jhipster8 build successful, then AggregateError

Tags: angular, jhipster

after upgrading my jhipster to latest, and tried to geenrate just the frontend using this cmd

```
jhipster --skip-server --db=sql --auth=jwt --jhi-prefix=cha --entity-suffix=cha
```

i'm facing this issue after running npm start, can any one help me please

```
Build at: 2023-11-07T14:56:41.490Z - Hash: cb3427b3361a0ecb - Time: 23318ms

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


√ Compiled successfully.
AggregateError
```

Answer (score 0):

i just downgraded my nodejs from latest to 18.18.2 LTS, and every think is ok now

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a recent [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/24134), the current workaround for this problem is to downgrade the Node version to 18.18.2. This is a temporary measure until JHipster updates their platform to be compatible with the latest Node versions. Keep an eye on the JHipster release notes for updates on when they've resolved this issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35403560)